# Running wordpress site different local host

Tags: wordpress

I have recently taken my first programming project and it is with word press, I have never used it before as I have only done hard coding HTML/CSS before. My client has given me all of the files of her site, how do I run this on wordpress. I have installed wordpress and can run the test123 site but when I do the same thing on the local server with the info she gave me then I get a "Error establishing a database connection". This is surprising because all of the file folders in the info she gave me is the same as the test site (obv the content is different). She was doing it on a mac and I am on windows but I assume that hsouldn't matter. How can I fix this so I can see the site on wordpress and make the required changes that she wanted.

Thanks!

I tried changing the config file but that just gives me the setup again and not the site she has already made :(

[image]

[image]

Comment: Beside files, you also need a database, that you have to load on your local machine.

Comment: I have created a database

Comment: I have initialized wordpress but how can I get the formatting she had for the site on my local host

Comment: But did you load her database in the newly created database? Just puting the files on the server does not magically import her database.

Comment: So what should be done. 1. get all files of the site. 2. export the database 3. put all files on the new location 4. import the database 5. change the connection settings in wp-config.php 6. convert the database for use on a new host using searchreplacesb2.php for instance

Comment: Basically, just do what is suggested here: https://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress

Comment: Okay, but first I need her to export the database on her local host and send it to me correct. Then I go into SQL and import that database right

Comment: Okay, I have the database now and imported it and that is good. I followed the steps and changed the wp-options. However, when I run the path L localhost/test123 it says that it refuses to connect and I can't get to the site :(

Answer (score 0):

First, create a folder into your htdocs folder with name test123
now put all the directory which one provide you by client  in to test123 folder like wp-admin , wp-content ....etc

after then in new tab run this path
http://localhost/phpmyadmin/
Create a database with name something test , then import the database which one provide to you by your client , after import go to table name wp-options and change the site url  http://localhost/test123 same for admin URL

Now back to your files and open wp-config.php file from your test123 folder root directory , change database name which one you recently created "test" 
username set to "root" and password "blank" hostname should be "localhost"

now run path in to URL  http://localhost/test123
after this if you want to login  http://localhost/test123/wp-admin

then first you need to change user password with md5 strings from database wp-user  table

the site will work on localhost

Comment: I'm not sure if my client provided me with the database information. She said she just copied the stuff from the MMAP folder. What would the database file look like?

Comment: ok if you have not database then just create a database and same database name use in your wp-config.php file

Comment: Okay, I have the database now and imported it and that is good. I followed your steps and changed the wp-options. However, when I run the path L http://localhost/test123 it says that it refuses to connect and I can't get to the site :(

Comment: I have wordpress setup and so it should be working right. Do I need to change something else in the file to make it work as part of the multisite?

Comment: which apache server are you using is this xampp ? or send me screenshots of problems

Comment: I am using WAMP. I will send you screenshots, thank you for your help

Comment: I put the screenshots in the main post, please let me know if you need anything else. I keep on trying things and it doesn't work. Very stressful

Answer (score 0):

Here some change for wordpress project on host to other host .

in your sql file change host name example

> 

to change

> http://localhost

after change to your config file details.

Answer (score 0):

installation WordPress in wamp server

first, start wamp server

[image]

click to start all services when it will work the icon will be colored green

Go to C:\wamp\www and paste WordPress folder there. You can rename the WordPress folder to anything you want for example test123

Now open a web browser and go to:

http://localhost/test123/

it will ask you for database connection error

now open the phpmyadmin as showing into create
a database and import the database

then go to you Wordpress folder test123 and find the wp-config.php file and replace your username with "root" database name you created , and password blank . now run http://localhost/test123/ once again

if not work then please come to chat box room.

Comment: Hello, I just started fresh with a new computer and ran all the steps and am STILL getting the localhost refused to connect error!

Comment: I did this on the new computer where wordpress is not installed, is that okay

Comment: On the new computer had you installed first wamp server ?

Comment: Yes, I installed WAMP and made sure it turned green first to see that all the services were running correctly

Comment: I posted it on the board there but it doesn't seem to be active

Comment: send me screenshot and please activate chat for a moment .

Comment: Hello, how do I activate chat? Now it is giving me a DNS error randomly instead of the previous localhost refuses error :(

Comment: I got through the DNS error by specifying the localhost in the url but am still getting the other refusing error

Comment: Hi Raj, please let me know when you can chat about this

Comment: i am available now