# Moving existing domain to Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

My friend has an existing website which is hosted by his current server, and fully working. However, the website is not made with Wordpress, and he is not satisfied with the design of the website. We have made a Wordpress website in localhost, and want to move the existing website(domain) to Wordpress but keep using the current server, is that possible? and anyone can to me how to do that? thanks.

Comment: if the server the old website is on is going to be the same server this wordpress build will be on then you should be able to upload the wordpress install and make some chnages to the database for the difference in baseurl and path between localhost and the server

Comment: Do you mean I can login to the C-Panel and install Wordpress and make some changes on the WP I newly installed, and then link the localhost to the server?

Comment: well you shouldn't be linking your localhost to any server. and yes while you could use c-panel to make a new wordpress install on your webserver and made the same changes you did on your localhost install i'd rather go for the option of uploading your wordpress build you've made along with it's database, generaly with a combination of ftp (for the wordpress file) and whatever database management software you have with your host (eg. phpmyadmin)

Comment: I got the idea, install a new Wordpress and combine the database with my current localhost wordpress's. Is that right? Do I need to do any other things? And one more thing, since the localhost Wordpress is not finishing as well, can I start to install the new Wordpress throught C-Panel and make the new Wordpress? What if I do this, will the website still be working with the old version? Or it will start using wordpress even thought there may be nothing on the new Wordpress? I don't know if I express my idea clearly. Thanks

Comment: there may be some database changes such as baseurl and path (can't recall the table name). the wordpress that will be on your webserver will be separate from your localhost one as such if you install a brand new, out of the box build of Wordpress it wont have any of the settings that your locahost one has (thus the database update), as for the old site on the server i don't know. i don't use c-panel to install wordpress rather i upload the files myself via ftp

Comment: I see. I will try first. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Check these overflows :

[Switch over WordPress Site server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38408274/switch-over-wordpress-site-server/38408306#38408306)

[Running wordpress site different local host](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38535261/running-wordpress-site-different-local-host/38539655#38539655)

if not work then do below 
first, export your localhost website database then
moves your localhost website's files to live to sever root directory , and then
create a database with username , password from PHPMyAdmin database wizard Cpanel , then open your database and import the database .

after that open imported database and open table wp-options , and change the site url and server url . and see the website will work .

if not work then comment on answer I will suggest you more .

Comment: Thanks so much. I will try it.